# How to define a object or struct as threadprivate in OpenMP?

Tags: c++, struct, openmp, private

I don't know how to make a struct or object as threadprivate, what I'm doing generates a error:

```
    struct point2d{
        int x;
        int y;
        point2d(){
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
        //copy constructor
        point2d(point2d& p){
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
        }
    };
```

I declare a static structure and try to make them threadprivate

```
    static  point2d myPoint;
    #pragma omp threadprivate(myPoint)
```

It generates an error:

> error C3057: 'myPoint' : dynamic initialization of 'threadprivate' symbols is not currently supported

Does it means that current openmp compiler doesn't support this to make a struct threadprivate? Or what I'm doing is wrong.
Is there any alternate way to pass a struct or object?

Here's rest part of my codes:

```
    void myfunc(){
        printf("myPoint at %p\n",&myPoint);
    }

    void main(){
    #pragma omp parallel
       {
           printf("myPoint at %p\n",&myPoint);
           myfunc();
       }

    }
```

Comment: Are you compiling this with a C compiler or C++? I see you tagged it as both. It looks like it may not like the constructor. To elaborate, it looks like it may not like that it would call a constructor to initialize the data, rather than a static copy from `.text`.

Comment: I'm using vc++, do you mean it's better to pass it manually?

Comment: It just appears to me that `threadprivate` variables need to be statically initialized. I'm not sure how to go about doing that without ditching the constructor, and just writing a function `initPoint2d(point2d& p, int inX, int inY)`. That violates 'the rules' of OO, though, I believe. I'm a C guy.

Comment: I didn't get that, where should I put the initPoint2d() function? In the constructor?

Comment: I'm totally confused about how to do static initialization. It seems like any constructor runs before main() are considered as static initialization, I tried this, but still generates this error

Comment: [MSVC seems to imply that it can hadle threadprivate classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z1788dd.aspx) but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: opps, that was the wrong link, here is the correct one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch691419.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ a struct with methods is a Class where the default is public.  It's not [plain-old-data (POD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure).  [MSVC seems to imply that it can handle threadprivate objects (i.e. non-POD)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch691419.aspx) but I can't seem to get it to work.  I did get it working in GCC like this:

```
extern point2d myPoint;
#pragma omp threadprivate(myPoint)
point2d myPoint;
```

But there is a work around which will work with MSVC (as well as GCC and ICC).  You can use threadprivate pointers.

The purpuse of threadprivate is to have private version of an object/type for each thread and have the values persistent between parallel regions. You can do that by delcaring a pointer to `point2d`, making that threadprivate, and then allocating memory for the private pointer for each thread in a parallel region. Make sure you delete the allocated memory at your last parallel call.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

struct point2d {
    int x;
    int y;
    point2d(){
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
    //copy constructor
    point2d(point2d& p){
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
    }
};      

static point2d *myPoint;
#pragma omp threadprivate(myPoint)

int main() {

    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        myPoint = new point2d();
        myPoint->x = omp_get_thread_num();
        myPoint->y = omp_get_thread_num()*10;
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            printf("thread %d myPoint->x %d myPoint->y %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(),myPoint->x, myPoint->y);
        }
    }   
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            printf("thread %d myPoint->x %d myPoint->y %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(),myPoint->x, myPoint->y);
        }
        delete myPoint;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you do in your code is completely correct. Quoting the OpenMP standard (emphasis mine):

> A threadprivate variable with class type must have:
>
> - **an accessible, unambiguous default constructor in case of default initialization without a given initializer**;
> - an accessible, unambiguous constructor accepting
>     the given argument in case of direct initialization;
> - an accessible, unambiguous copy constructor in case of copy initialization with an explicit initializer.

The one in bold seems exactly your case.

The behavior you encounter seems a [missing feature or a bug in the compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbebdw4k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Strangely enough,  even [GCC seems to have problem with that](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=27557), while Intel is claimed to work fine.

Comment: GCC works fine.  You do `extern point2d myPoint; #pragma ompthreadprivate(myPoint) <newline> point2d myPoint;`  Here is a working example in GCC http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f156e0122760fe12

Comment: @Zboson Here it's the keyword static that [seems to trigger the error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e861eb25b53073a) on non-POD types

Comment: Change static to extern and remove the delcarations of myPoint in that example and it works http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a274f6a4c5f63568

Comment: Using threadprivate pointers as I suggested seems to be a good cross-compiler solution but it's easy to make errors onallocation/reallocation.  There's no ideal solution.

Comment: @Zboson Yes, but then you need to define the variable elsewhere, and apply the same threadprivate directive in another file scope. If you use a POD type the example I linked works, and as far as I can see there's nothing in the standard preventing it to work even with non-POD type.

Comment: @Massimiliano Thank you or your answer. According to your post, do I still need copy constructor?

Comment: If I pass a variable from serial to parallel, does it consider to be initialize event or copy event? For my understanding `firstprivate` and `lastprivate` are considered as copy event, but how about `threadprivate`?

Comment: @CharlesChow it depends on how you define the static variable. If you define it by copy-construction, then you need a copy-constructor. Otherwise you'll need an ordinary constructor.