# c++ openmp and threadprivate

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm in a situation where on one computer (cluster with high perf nodes) a code
compiles but on my personal computer it doesn't.

The error is

```
'var' declared 'threadprivate' after first use.
#pragma omp threadprivate(var)
```

The related line in the code is in a header file and looks like this

```
extern const int var;
#pragma omp threadprivate(var);
```

I haven't written the code so it is difficult to give a minimal example of the
problem.

Here are some specification of the computer I use :

- cluster (compiles)

  - red hat 7.5
  - <del>gcc 4.8.3</del> **EDIT** intel 15.0.0
  - openmp version date : 2011.07 : don't have permission to access yum/apt/...
- personal computer (doesn't compile)

  - debian 8.0
  - gcc 4.9.2
  - openmp version date : 2013.07 : libgomp1 v 4.9.2-10

I know there is not enough information, but does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I recall there was a bug in GCC 4.8 related to ...private const but I can't remember the details to know if it's related.  But I think this might be incorrect code, since you can't have global data as thread private (AFAIK).

Comment: [how-to-define-a-object-or-struct-as-threadprivate-in-openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552077/how-to-define-a-object-or-struct-as-threadprivate-in-openmp/23559230#23559230)

Comment: @jeff, thread private converts a statically allocated variable (with global or file scope) to a statically allocated variable for each thread.

Comment: @Jeff thx for your comment... unfortunately, I don't see how it could help me

Comment: @Zboson int is a POD, right ? the link you provided is for non POD.

Comment: @PinkFloyd, yeah `int` is POD. I thought the link would be interesting nevertheless. I have not had time to look at this yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [omp with gcc and intel compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663476/omp-with-gcc-and-intel-compiler)