# omp with gcc and intel compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, openmp, intel

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922764/c-openmp-and-threadprivate) question, the use of `threadprivate` with openmp is
problematic. Here is a minimum (non-)working example of the problem:

```
#include"omp.h"
#include<iostream>

extern const int a;
#pragma omp threadprivate(a)

const int a=2;

void my_call(){
    std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
};

int main(){
#pragma omp parallel for
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<8;i++){
        my_call();
    }
}
```

This codes compiles with intel 15.0.2.164 but not with gcc 4.9.2-10. 
gcc says:

```
g++ -std=c++11  -O3 -fopenmp    -O3 -fopenmp  test.cpp   -o test
test.cpp:5:29: error: ‘a’ declared ‘threadprivate’ after first use
#pragma omp threadprivate(a)
```

I would be very happy to find a way to compile it with gcc.

Note: I know that global variables are a nightmare, but this example is the
coming from a code I haven't written and that I need to use... It's >11000
lines and I don't want to rewrite everything.

Comment: Please add some information about the error/failure you experience.

Comment: @fuesika, sorry forgot about that :-)

Comment: Are you aware of http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33 ?

Comment: Do you really need this to be const ? (Drop the const and it'll compile in gcc, or drop the pragma as you don't really need it to be threadprivate if it's const.)

Comment: Did you try:

    #pragma omp threadprivate(a)
    extern const int a;

?

Comment: @fuesika, I think what you are referring to is for non-POD types... right ? in which case it's not my problem

Comment: @Christian, thanks but it doesn't compile either...

Comment: @nos, I think I will drop the pragma as this changes nothing because it's a global variable that will be accessible for all threads. But what if each threads needs a different const a? I haven't read the 11000 lines of the code and I  don't know if this situation is possible.

Comment: do `extern const int a = 2` and remove `const int a=2`;

Comment: The code compiles with GCC 4.8 and earlier. I guess something in the parser has changed since 4.9 and remained so as GCC 5.1 is failing with the same error.