# How to use direct initialization of an object in OpenMP threadprivate directives?

Tags: c++, openmp

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552077/how-to-define-a-object-or-struct-as-threadprivate-in-openmp) question one of the answers cite the following part of the OpenMP standard:

> A threadprivate variable with class type must have:
>
> - an accessible, unambiguous default constructor in case of default initialization without a given initializer;
> - an accessible, unambiguous constructor accepting the given argument in case of direct initialization;
> - an accessible, unambiguous copy constructor in case of copy initialization with an explicit initializer.

Using (almost) the same example on the posted question, what I want to do is:

```cpp
struct point2d{
        int x;
        int y;
        point2d(){
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
        //copy constructor
        point2d(point2d& p){
            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;
        }
    };
```

And declare two `point` variables of type `point2d`:

```cpp
point2d global_point;
point2d local_point(global_point);

#pragma omp threadprivate(local_point)
```

I see that on the example used in the question posted the code failed due to the first item on the cited part of the OpenMP standard (as pointed in the answer).

My question is, on my case, how can I use the second point of the OpenMP standard to direct initialize the private `local_point` variables (all using the `global_point`)?

Also, does it make any sense or I've completely missed the point in that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reasons discussed in the post you linked, and for certain compilers, you can't do this either. I guess that was the whole point. It is a missing feature, and the compiler doesn't even try to hide it:

> C3057: dynamic initialization of 'threadprivate' symbols is *not currently* supported

What is it you try to achieve? With this trivial structure, you can

```
const int gx = 3;
const int gy = -2;
point2d local_point = {gx, gx+gy};
#pragma omp threadprivate ( local_point )
```

but you have to stick to `const` fundamental types. If you wanted to initialize your `threadprivate` variable (must be `static`) inside a function you can use `copyin` (it would use the third item, the copy assignment, naturally)

```
void foo()
{
    static point2d local_point;
#pragma omp threadprivate( local_point )
    local_point = global_point;
#pragma omp parallel copyin( local_point )
    { // do something
```

or even better

```
{
    point2d local_point( global_point );
#pragma omp parallel firstprivate( local_point )
    { // do something
```

to break free from restrictions.